# multicolumn tabular is not adding column separator lines

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, multicolumn, tabulary

I have a table like:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{scriptsize}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular}[m]{|m{2cm}|*{17}{c}|c|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Model} & 
\multicolumn{17}{c|}{APE Thresholds (\%)} & \multirow{3}{*}{Best} \\ \cline{2-18}
& 0.01 & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.25 & 0.5 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 7.5 & 10 & 15 & 30 & 40 & 50 & 75 & 100 & None \\\hline
Open dfasdfadsfaa 
& 35 & 40 & 55 & 25 & 40 & 35 & \\
Closed 
& 25 & 50 & 35 & 40 & 45 &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Hyperparameter Optimisation: APE Threshold - Words \& Depgram Features}
\label{table2}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{table}
```

Which looks like:

[image]

As you can see, there is a gap to the right of the word `Best`, which should be the end of the table.

What am I doing wrong/how can I improve this table? I had to set up the tab column separation to very small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to improve the table is to give it a more "open" look -- by removing all vertical lines and using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package for the horizontal lines. To assure that the tabular material takes up the entire available text block width, use a `tabular*` environment. And, as it appears to be necessary to render the table using `\scriptsize`, reduce the font size of the caption as well; in the example below, I use one of the facilities of the `caption` to set the font size of the caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,caption,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\captionsetup{size=footnotesize}
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let tabular* figure out intercolumn whitespace

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight}p{2cm} @{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{18}{c}}
\toprule
Model & \multicolumn{17}{c}{APE Thresholds (\%)} & Best \\ 
\cmidrule{2-18}
& 0.01 & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.25 & 0.5 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 7.5 & 10 & 15 & 30 & 40 & 50 & 75 & 100 & None \\
\midrule
Open dfasdfadsfaa
& 35 & 40 & 55 & 25 & 40 & 35 & \\
Closed
& 25 & 50 & 35 & 40 & 45 &  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Hyperparameter Optimisation: APE Threshold---Words \& Depgram Features}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

even the columns are empty, you alwas need to set all ampersands. because you didn't do this, the last cell, which end with vertical line, never appear ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{scriptsize}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}[m]{|m{2cm}|*{17}{c}|c|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Model} &
\multicolumn{17}{c|}{APE Thresholds (\%)} & 
    \multirow{3}{*}{Best} \\ \cline{2-18}
& 0.01 & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.25 & 0.5 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 7.5 & 10 & 15 & 30 & 40 & 50 & 75 & 100 & None &    \\\hline
Open dfasdfadsfaa
& 35 & 40 & 55 & 25 & 40 & 35 & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
Closed
& 25 & 50 & 35 & 40 & 45 & & &  & & & & &  & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Hyperparameter Optimisation: APE Threshold - Words \& Depgram Features}
\label{table2}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
off-topic of your question, but mybe you consider to design table without vertical lines. With employing rules from `booktabs` package you can obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{showframe}% for showing page layout
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{green!50}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}X*{18}{c}}
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{17}{c}{APE Thresholds (\%)} &   
                            \\  \cmidrule(lr){2-18}
\centering  Model   
        & 0.01 & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.25 & 0.5 &  1 &  2 & 5 
        & 7.5  & 10   & 15  & 30   & 40  & 50 & 75 & 100 
        & None & Best       \\  \midrule
Open dfas dfads faa
        & 35   & 40   & 55  & 25   & 40  & 35 &    & 
        &      &      &     &      &     &    &    & 
        &      &            \\  \addlinespace
Closed
        & 25   & 50   & 35  & 40   & 45  &    &    &  
        &      &      &     &      &     &    &    & 
        &      &            \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Hyperparameter Optimisation: APE Threshold - Words \& Depgram Features}
\label{table2}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Observe the changes between above MWE and your code:

- even in editor the ampersands are positioned such, that it is easy to recognize columns and see, if are all present
- `scriptsize` is not an environemt, so use it as command. Inside group (defined by `table` environment) it has influence only on table content
- the use of `multirow` package isn't necessary
- assed package `tabularx` is exploited for fit table to text width.
- by reducing `\tabcolsep` to 2pt and used `tabularx` table environment enable to increase font size used in table to `\small`

Comment: Off-topic :-) -- Both `tabular` environments appear to be wider than the text block. Any suggested remedies?

Answer (score 2):

Please observe the solution only for the part of table in question. Changing `3` to `2` in `\multirow` gives a better effect. If you want also final vertical line in the rest of your table, you should add proper number of `&`'s.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{scriptsize}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular}[m]{|m{2cm}|*{17}{c}|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Model} & 
%\multicolumn{17}{c|}{APE Thresholds (\%)} & \multirow{3}{*}{Best} \\ \cline{2-18}
\multicolumn{17}{c|}{APE Thresholds (\%)} & \multirow{2}{*}{Best} \\ \cline{2-18}
& 0.01 & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.25 & 0.5 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 7.5 & 10 & 15 & 30 & 40 & 50 & 75 & 100 & None &\\\hline
Open dfasdfadsfaa 
& 35 & 40 & 55 & 25 & 40 & 35 & \\
Closed 
& 25 & 50 & 35 & 40 & 45 &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Hyperparameter Optimisation: APE Threshold - Words \& Depgram Features}
\label{table2}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]